# How to change button image added to TableView section header

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I've added a button to section header which shows a view on clicking it. My need is that I've to show an "Up-arrow" image while view is shown and "Down-arrow" image when view is hidden.

How can I achieve this? Please help me ...

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 316, 60)];
            [btn setTag:section];
            [aView addSubview:btn];
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(sectionTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest that you can have 2 images - 1 for 'Up' and 1 for 'Down' arrow.
Set default image to the btn for state UIControlStateNormal and set the other image for state UIControlStateSelected.
Now in your sectionTapped: method just change the state of the button.
So when you show or hide your view you need to set the button selected YES/NO.

Hope this helps.

Comment: one thing that actually the button I'm adding is to section header and  I need to have this changing in right of this button. so, should I need to add one more button or imageview on right side......

Comment: No.. You can make the image such that it shows the arrow on the right side and may be transparent in remaining area. Set this image to the button. No need to have an ImageView.

Comment: but actually the button is of width section header right.... then how comes.... image should be small on right side on this button.. how to approach this please...

Comment: Using some softwares like PhotoShop it is possible to create images which are transparent in some parts and have visible image in some part combined in one image. It will be easier if you can have such an image. So basically you can have image with same width as your button.Set this image to the button as background may be. No need to have an ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

You can trying using BOOL to check if the button has been pressed or not and animate to rotate the image in your button to point up or down.

```
-(IBAction)dropdownBtnClicked:(id)sender 
{

      [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

      [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

      if (!isDropdownEnabled) 
      { 
         //BOOL - checking if the button has been pressed or not

          isDropdownEnabled=TRUE;
          drpDwnBtn.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(270/180*M_PI);
      }

      else 
      {

          isDropdownEnabled=FALSE;

          drpDwnBtn.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);

       }

      [UIView commitAnimations];

  }
```

Comment: If you want the button to be that image, you can simply go to button property and set the background image, but since your doing programmatically, you can do this by adding this piece of code - [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"updownimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 1):

I had done this before in one of my app.

Take this code as `Reference`

1.Specific Method.

```
- (void)methodName:(UIButton *)sender
 {
 int i = [sender.titleLabel.text intValue];
 NSNumber *numb;
if(i == 0)
{
    numb = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
   sender.titleLabel.text = @"1";
   [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
 }
else
{
numb = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
sender.titleLabel.text = @"0";
[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
}
```

2.Setting UIButton Programatically in UITabelview viewForHeaderInSection.

```
 UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 20, 30, 30)];

[button addTarget:self
       action:@selector(methodName:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
 button.tag = section;
 if([[sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section] boolValue])
 {
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
button.titleLabel.text = @"0";
 }
 else
 {
  [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
  button.titleLabel.text = @"1";
  }
```

Comment: I've added button to total section header like "didSelectRowAtIndexpath" functionality... and I need to show that scenario on right side of this button... how to proceed..

Comment: You Just need to set frame of UIButton in 2nd method what ever you want.