# How to change an image I set in tableView(_:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:)?

Tags: ios, swift, header, tableview

I set an image for each tableView's header section in tableView(_:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:) in this way:

```
    let image = UIImage(named: "arrow-down")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 220, y: 12, width: 10, height: 5)
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    header.addSubview(imageView)
```

To try to change the image (it's a chevron I use to show the possibility to collapse the section) I tried in this way but it sets the top header only, instead I would like to replace the image in the specific section (I have got the section item Int):

```
    let frame = CGRect(x: 220, y: 12, width: 10, height: 5)
    let headerImageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "arrow-up")!
    headerImageView.image = image // sets the top header only
```

How can I change the image displayed at a specific section?

I read this question [How to change button image added to TableView section header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229910/how-to-change-button-image-added-to-tableview-section-header) but I have not a button in the section.

I also found other similar questions but I don't know well Objective-C and can't convert the code easily in current Swift without to get errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
If you know the specific position, you can do it at the moment when the table is loading the elements if what you want is to add an initial image (Option 1), if what you want is that when you touch the cell change the image you can do it the following way (Option 2)

-----------
Option 1
-----------
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     if(indexPath.row == //index of your cell){ 
      let frame = CGRect(x: 220, y: 12, width: 10, height: 5)
      let headerImageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
      let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "arrow-up")!
      headerImageView.image = image
     }
}

-----------
Option 2
-----------

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     if(indexPath.row == //index of your cell){ 
      let frame = CGRect(x: 220, y: 12, width: 10, height: 5)
      let headerImageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
      let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "arrow-up")!
      headerImageView.image = image
     }
}
```